# What does z-index:1001 means in css

Tags: html, css, z-index

i already know that z-index defines the stack level of the box in the current context but does z-index means anything special(the same for 9999)? Because they are used so often..

e.g.

```
.outerBox{
  display:block;
  z-index:1001;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp Is it simple, isn't it?

Comment: If someone were to add a popup with a `z-index: 1000` to your web-page, `.outerBox` would still be visible. Could be precautionary. There's nothing 'special' about it.

Comment: *just a comment:* `z-index` requires `position:absolute;` or `position:fixed;` or `position:relative;` in the case of "relative" the effect of "z-index" is different from "absolute"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same purpose as `z-index: 9999`. It's an ugly hack that moves absolute/relative/fixed 
elements to the front.

Comment: all the positioned elemets.

Comment: Read the manual: `Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).`

Comment: Why *ugly*? It just does what it's supposed to do.

Comment: I just think it's rather arbitrary, it's better to place depths relatively.

Comment: so why to put 9999 and not something bigger? is there any special reason, thats the original question. @lolka_bolka you didn't got what i am asking, i know what z-index does but i ask why to put such values.

Comment: It just needs to work. 9999 is what people usually do, as there's usually less than 9999 elements on the page.

Comment: Usually developers use values from 1 to 10, because they knows, how they build their own elements. But if you are using a 3rd party thing, then you can't be sure, what is the bigger z-index, so try to set it a really big value.

Answer (score 3):

`z-index` defines which positioned element appears on top (Sort of like layers).

So `z-index: 1000` would appear on top of a `z-index 999`.

Doing `z-index: 1001` is an an attempt to appear "on top" of a item with `z-index: 1000`

Answer (score 3):

As  mentioned above it is used for stacking elements. If they or their pieces are positioned at same place, the one with higher `z-index` will be on top.

In this simple example, there are two same structures, yet in first with visible class yellow div will be on top, in second will be not, depending on `z-index` settings.

```
<div class='container'>
<div class='red'></div>
<div class='yellow visible'></div>
</div>
<div class='container'>
<div class='red'></div>
<div class='yellow notvisible'></div>
</div
```

and part of CSS:

```
.red { top:0; z-index:10;}
.yellow {top:0;}    
.visible {z-index:20;}
.notvisible {z-index:5;}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/h1tcv7d1/)